# Is there a combinatorial formula to rewrite bivariate linear product?

Tags: combinatorics

If I have the following product: $$(x)(x+\lambda_1-1)(x+\lambda_2-1) \dots(x+\lambda_m-1)$$ is there a way to rewrite it in summation notation? I've got that I could try to rewrite it as $$(x)((x+\lambda_1)-1)((x+\lambda_2)-1) \dots((x+\lambda_m)-1)$$ and treat the $x+\lambda_i$ as one variable but then I would have to write separate summation for that. Or I can rewrite as $$(x)(x+(\lambda_1-1))(x+(\lambda_2-1)) \dots(x+(\lambda_m-1))$$ but Im still not sure where to go from there

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas